# Regular Expressions Theory Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I have some old exercises of regular expressions without solutions and i would like to check if i understand the theory correctly. In the methodology section i show my answers/steps so far.

After the arrow ( -> ) is my answer to every problem.

1.Give the **smallest** possible string that languages i) and ii) **don't** accept

i)b*(ab)*a* -> aab

ii)b*(a+ba)*b* -> abba

2.Given the regular expressions r=a*+b* and s=ab* + ba* + b*a + (a*b)* . Find the **smallest** possible string that can be expressed in:

i)r but not in s -> {empty-ε}

ii)s but not in r -> aba

iii)both r and s -> {x} there is no answer

iv)cannot be expressed in any of them -> aaba

3.Give the expression that accepts strings that:

i)have 3*x a's character -> b*(b*ab*ab*a)*b*

ii)start or end with ab/ba -> (ab+ba)(a+b)* +(b+a)*(ab+ba)

iii)dont have aaa in them -> (b+ab+aab)*(a+aa+ε)

iv)every b is followed by aaa -> a*(baaa)*a*

## **METHODOLOGY**

1. 

i) After two a the regex can't go back and accept a b.

ii) After abb cannot accept anything other than b

2)
i)The empty string because s accepts at least the characters aba

ii)aba cannot be accepted by r since it can't have a after b*

iii) No answer since the smallest possible strings aren't the same.

iv) aaba in r you can't have aab_ with _ = other than b and s can't accept aaba.

3)
i)There are always 3*x a's in the string with any number of b's.

ii)Any string between start/end is arbitary.

iii)Every possible string that does not have aaa (so states end with b).

iv)No criterion for a's but every b should be followed by aaa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors.

2(i) isn’t right: the $(a^*b)^*$ term in $s$ accepts the empty string. However, $s$ does not accept $aa$, which is accepted by $r$.

2(iii) isn’t right: the empty string can be expressed in both.

Another possibility for 2(iv) is $bbaa$.

3(i) is correct but can be simplified to $(b^*ab^*ab^*a)^*b^*$, and $(b^*ab^*ab^*ab^*)^*$ also works.

3(iv) isn’t right: it doesn’t recognize $baaaabaaa$, for instance. $a^*(baaaa^*)^*$ will work.